# getTables().getHeight does not work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I insert a table in an empty slide. Then I fill it with different texts. After this I want to get the height of the table. The result from .getHeight is null. The .getHeight method works good for shapes and images, but not for tables. How can I get the table height?

```
function getTableHeight(){

     var presentation = SlidesApp.openById('myPresentationId');    
     var slides = presentation.getSlides();
     var slideId = 'mySlideId';
     var slide = slides.filter(function(e){return e.getObjectId() == slideId})[0]; 

     slide.insertTable(5, 5);

     var tableHeight = slide.getTables()[0].getHeight();

     Logger.log(tableHeight);

}
```

Here is the full script. It works fine, but I need a function to split the imported table, when there is not enough space on the slide.

```
function getTableFromSpreadsheetoToSlides(){

  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById('myPresentationId');
  var slideId = "mySlideId";
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  var slide = slides.filter(function(e){return e.getObjectId() == slideId})[0]; 

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('mySpreadsheetId');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ActionItems');

  var numRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var numColumns = sheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns();

  var values = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, numRows, numColumns).valueOf();

  var table = slide.getTables()[0];

  var numRowsToDelete = table.getNumRows() - 1;

  // remove old tableRows except the table head
  for (i = numRowsToDelete; i > 0; i--) {
    table.getRow(i).remove();
  }

  // new imported table rows append to the existing table head
  for ( var i = 1; i < numRows; i++ ) {

      table.appendRow();

      for ( var j = 0; j < numColumns; j++ ) {

        var text = table.getCell(i, j).getText().setText(values[i][j]);

      }

      // HERE I need a query how long the table in slide is. If it is longer/higher than the slide is, it should be split and the next row should go to a new slide

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this workaround? `getHeight()` cannot be used for Table as @Randy D says. So I propose a workaround using Slides API.

- When the slide information is retrieved using `Slides.Presentations.Pages.get()` of Slides API, the information of tables is also included. In the information, the height and width of table are also included.
- But the unit is EMU (English Metric Unit), and the height and width is separated by each cell. So it is required to sum each height and width while modifying the unit.

The modified script reflected this is as follows.

In order to use this script, please enable Slides API at [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) and [API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/slides.googleapis.com/?q=slides).

### Sample script :

```
function getTableHeight(){
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById('myPresentationId');
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  var slideId = 'mySlideId';
  var slide = slides.filter(function(e){return e.getObjectId() == slideId})[0]; 
  slide.insertTable(5, 5);

  // Added scripts from here
  var pageElements = Slides.Presentations.Pages.get(presentation.getId(), slideId).pageElements;
  var result = [];
  for (var i in pageElements) {
    var rowHeight = 0;
    var rowWidth = 0;
    if (pageElements[i].table) {
      for (var j in pageElements[i].table.tableRows) {
        rowHeight += pageElements[i].table.tableRows[j].rowHeight.magnitude / 12700;
      }
      for (var k in pageElements[i].table.tableColumns) {
        rowWidth += pageElements[i].table.tableColumns[k].columnWidth.magnitude / 12700;
      }
      result.push({Height: rowHeight, Width: rowWidth});
    }
  }
  Logger.log(result)
}
```

### Note :

- Unit of output values is point.
- Because 12,700 EMUs per point, each values retrieved by `pageElements[i].table.tableRows[j].rowHeight.magnitude` and `pageElements[i].table.tableColumns[k].columnWidth.magnitude` are required to be divided by 12,700.
- When there are several tables in the slide, this sample script retrieves the width and height for each table.

### Reference :

- [About the unit of EMU](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/Unit)

### Edit :

#### Flow of additional script :

1. Retrieve the page height of slides.
2. Retrieve the height of one row for the exisiting table.

   - In your script, the table has only one row.
3. Calculate the number of rows to append.
4. Calculate the remaining rows.
5. Add rows and values from spreadsheet.

#### Modified script :

```
function getTableFromSpreadsheetoToSlides(){

  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById('myPresentationId');
  var slideId = "mySlideId";
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  var slide = slides.filter(function(e){return e.getObjectId() == slideId})[0]; 

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('mySpreadsheetId');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ActionItems');

  var numRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var numColumns = sheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns();

  var values = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, numRows, numColumns).valueOf();

  var table = slide.getTables()[0];

  var numRowsToDelete = table.getNumRows() - 1;

  // remove old tableRows except the table head
  for (i = numRowsToDelete; i > 0; i--) {
    table.getRow(i).remove();
  }

  // From here, I added and modified script.
  var pageHeight = Slides.Presentations.get(presentation.getId()).pageSize.height.magnitude / 12700;
  var rowHeight = getTableHeight(presentation.getId(), slideId);
  var additionalRows = Math.floor(pageHeight / rowHeight);
  var remainingRows = numRows - additionalRows; // You can add the remaining rows using this.
  for ( var i = 1; i < additionalRows; i++ ) { // Modified
    table.appendRow();
    for ( var j = 0; j < numColumns; j++ ) {
      var text = table.getCell(i, j).getText().setText(values[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

function getTableHeight(slidesId, slideId) {
  var pageElements = Slides.Presentations.Pages.get(slidesId, slideId).pageElements;
  var result = [];
  for (var i in pageElements) {
    var rowHeight = 0;
    var rowWidth = 0;
    if (pageElements[i].table) {
      for (var j in pageElements[i].table.tableRows) {
        rowHeight += pageElements[i].table.tableRows[j].rowHeight.magnitude / 12700;
      }
      for (var k in pageElements[i].table.tableColumns) {
        rowWidth += pageElements[i].table.tableColumns[k].columnWidth.magnitude / 12700;
      }
      result.push({Height: rowHeight, Width: rowWidth});
    }
  }
  return result[0].Height;
}
```

#### Note :

- This sample script can be used for the case that the each cell height is the same, as you said "each row has the same height".
- `getTableHeight()` can be used for the slide with several tables. But in this case, it supposes that there is one table in the slide.
- This sample script can be used for the case that the table has already been existing. Because when in one running, when the table is created, the created table couldn't retrieve. It couldn't do even if it uses `saveAndClose()`. I don't know the reason.

  - So until this is solved, please use this sample script for the slide that the table was created.

Comment: Thank you, but each row has the same height, no matter how much content is in the cell. The rowHeight is always equal minRowHeight. My goal was to display a table imported from Spreadsheet. But if this is longer than one slide, the rows should automatically be displayed on the next slide.

Comment: @Roberto B I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In your case, which height before and after importing do you want to know? Should you compare the height of slide and table of spreadsheet before importing? In my environment, although I copied and pasted a table of spreadsheet with over height of one slide, the table was not displayed in 2 pages. So I couldn't reproduce your situation. Can you show us about your method for importing the table of spreadsheet?

Comment: I import a table from Spreadsheet. This is sometimes shorter and sometimes longer. During the import to slides I want to get the height of the table. If the table is longer/higher than the slide, I want to split the table and display the second part of the table on slide 2.

Comment: @Roberto B Can I ask you about the method for importing? When you use script, please add it to your question.

Comment: I was looking at the Slides advanced API before posting my answer and wondering how it would work. I learned a new thing today. Definitely a heck of a workaround.

Comment: @Randy D Thank you for updating your question. By this, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. But there are some limitations. So please also read the note.

Comment: It is not so good, that each cell must have the same height. But it's ok :) Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @Tanaike: I have definitely different row heights. No row has the same height like another. But each row has the same minRowHeight and rowHeight in the respone of `Slides.Presentations.Pages.get(slidesId, slideId).pageElements`: "tableRowProperties":{"minRowHeight":{"unit":"EMU","magnitude":305275}},"rowHeight":{"unit":"EMU","magnitude":305275}} --- Is this a fault in Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Roberto B ``minRowHeight`` means the minimum height of rows. So I use ``rowHeight``. The reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/tables#tablerowproperties). If I misunderstand your comment, please tell me.

Comment: Yes, I know. You misunderstood me. Sorry.

Comment: Only the values of `minRowHeight` and `rowHeight` are always the same. The values belong to the first row. All following rows have the same height as the first row. No matter how much text is in the cell, the height never changes. I see this in the response of `Slides.Presentations.Pages.get(slidesId, slideId).pageElements`

Comment: @Roberto B Thank you for the additional information. I could study from your question.

Comment: @Tanaike Here you can find my test files: [spreadsheet with table](https://drive.google.com/open?id=152pEy-2245jW05gxp0F9Qp6UVa7pMciq14bS085iS2g) and the [presentation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yACGUAs7f2LVBiYkpQvXtK3vtGyrGL4he8f7EVsySoA) / The script is in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Roberto B You pointed out that although the "magnitude" of each row height is the same, the actual row heights are different. Is my understanding correct? I also experienced the same situation. I'm looking for the reason yet.

Comment: @Roberto B When I found the reason and workaround, I would like to let you know.

Comment: Yes, the actual row heights are different and the "magnitude", retrieved by using Slides.Presentations.Pages.get(), is always the same. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

The `getHeight()` method is not compatible with Tables.

See the limitations chart on the developer page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/moving-elements